# Type casting (structs) combined with Binding

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding, state

I have a view `DetailView` that needs parameter `input` which is of the type `Binding<MyType>`. And I have an array `@State var myArray = [myProtocol]()`, and I want initialize one `DetailView` for each object in `myArray`. `MyType` is conform to the protocol `myProtocol`.

How can I initialize a `DetailView` with the binding of `myArray[0]`? Because I cant type cast it like this `DetailView(input: $myArray[0] as! Binding<MyType>`? Is there any easy way?

For explanation why i can't just declare `myArray` as an array of type `[MyType]`: There are other types in this array which also conform to the protocol.

My code in a nutshell:

```swift
protocol myProtocol {
     var field1: String { get set }
     var field2: String { get set }
 }
 
 struct myTypeOne: myProtocol {
     var field1: String
     var field2: String
     // Some other Fields only myTypeOne has
 }
 
 struct myTypeTwo: myProtocol {
     var field1: String
     var field2: String
     // Some other Fields only myTypeTwo has
 }
 
 struct SubView: View {
     @Binding var item: myTypeOne
     var body: some View {
         // Some View Stuff
     }
 }
 
 struct myView: View {
     @State var list = [myProtocol]()
     var body: some View {
         VStack {
             ForEach(list, id: \.self){ element in
                 if type(of: element) == myTypeOne.self {
                     // Element is of type myTypeOne
                     // How can I now init SubView here
                     SubView(item: ???)
                 } else {
                     // Element is of type myTypeTwo
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Without your code it's difficult to know whether you made any mistake in your logic.

Comment: I'll provide some more code

Comment: `id: \.self` will crash, best fix that first before going generic

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution (because casting is bad by-default) is to bind to protocol, like

```
 struct SubView: View {
     @Binding var item: myProtocol    // << here !!

// ...
```

and then we can use

```
 var body: some View {
     VStack {
         ForEach($list, id: \.id){ element in   // << binding
                 SubView(item: element)         // << here !!
```

*assuming making `myProtocol` to have `id` for identification